# Properly centering elements with horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I have a list of div elements which are displayed with a horizontal scrollbar.

All elements inside those divs are (horizontally) centered, which is good, but they are not aligned correctly

I have the following structure

```
<div>
  <div>
    <img />
    <p />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img />
    <p />
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kSnq4/

If you look at the jsFiddle you'll see what the problem is. All elements should be aligned to the top.

Am i doing this the right way? If so, what should i do to fix it?

Comment: `.templateList .listItem {
vertical-align: top;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `vertical-align: top;` to your list-items. Also add `overlfow-y: hidden;` to `.templateList` if you want to prevent the vertical scrollbar.

```
.templateList .listItem{
    width:120px;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kSnq4/4/)

Comment: This did it. Thanks! I knew it was something as simple as that ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `vertical-align: top;` since you are using display: inline-block;

An example : http://jsfiddle.net/kSnq4/2/